# How to hide one section in PDF using iText7

Tags: c#, itext

Based on condition I need to hide one section and the section below should move above. So that while generating the PDF the hidden section should not show as  blank.

Comment: Can you please provide some code that you have tried, and some specific problems that you have found?

Comment: Your question is wrong. You can't be talking about PDF because your requirement goes against the PDF specification. You are probably talking about HTML, .docx, .txt, RTF,...

Answer (score 1):

Some clarification:

If you are doing this with an existing pdf, it is not likely to work. Pdf documents are not WYSIWYG format. Think of them more as containers of drawing-instructions than as containers of text.

Moving a section of an existing document will not work because:

- the document itself contains no information on what instructions go together to make up lines, paragraphs, and sections
- the document uses compression and byte-offsets, moving or deleting part of it would imply that you need to re-calculate all the byte-offsets

If you drop the requirement of re-flowing the text, it is certainly possible. iText already has an add-on for that called pdfSweep which look at all the drawing and rendering operations and removes the ones that intersect with a given rectangle (or adjusts them, for instance when a path goes through the rectangle)

If you are generating the pdf, this is of course trivial. You can simply do something like:

```
File outputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"output.pdf");
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

if(some_condition)
{
   layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"));
}
layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph("Never gonna give you up. Never gonna let you down."));
```

Check out http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep